# javaexec is not part of java plugin

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm a newbie to Gradle, and what I know that Gradle is a general build tool, also it uses plugins concept to extends its functionality. One of the Gradle plugins is the Java plugin in which there are all needed tasks build, testing and packaging java app.

So why execution of java is not part of that plugin and JavaExec task is part of the core Gradle functionality?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking - there are tasks and functions that allow you execute Java programs (namely the `project.javaexec` function and `JavaExec` task) that can be used for any purpose.

Comment: @mkobit as I said I'm a newbie that's why I'm asking to learn. what I mean the JavaExec is a java specific task so why it isn't defined in the java plugin itself?

Comment: The Java plugin is mainly concerned for use with building and testing Java projects. The `JavaExec` and `project.javaexec` are used to execute Java programs. For example, you may to take the output of your `java` project and execute a `public static void main` from that project. You can use either of the methods before to do that. However, you have a Python, or native, or really any project that needs to execute a Java program as part of its build process, you will want to make use of `JavaExec` or `project.javaexec`.

Comment: @mkobit I understand now thanks a lot